# azure AD adalAuthenticationService not able to read the token

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am developing a sample application which uses Azure Ad authentication services, i use adal-angular, adal js to perform validation, i can able to login successfully, but after that i cannot interpret the received token, Can anyone please help me to find what i am missing?

Code snippet:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","AdalAngular"]);
app.config(["$httpProvider","adalAuthenticationServiceProvider",function($httpProvider,adalProvider) {


    /*var endpoints ={
            "http://localhost:8080/index.jsp/":"https://thirumalaivstgit.onmicrosoft.com/sampangular"
    };*/
    adalProvider.init(
            {
                instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
                tenant: "thirumalaivstgit.onmicrosoft.com",
                clientId: "f1f7aafc-8901-4755-bb66-a46eae527e33",
                redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/index.jsp'                
            },$httpProvider);
}]);

app.controller("getvaluecontroller",["$scope","$http","adalAuthenticationService",function($scope,$http,adalService){
    $scope.appname="dfsfgggsgsdg";
    $scope.claims = [];
    $scope.login=function(){
        var loginvalue=adalService.login();
        console.log(loginvalue);
    }

    $scope.userSignedIn=function(err, token)
    {
         console.log('userSignedIn called');
          if (!err) {
              console.log("token: " + token);

          }
          else {
              console.error("error: " + err);
          }
    }

    $scope.logout=function(){
        adalService.logOut();
    }

    $scope.afterlogin=function()
    {
        console.log("afterlogin::" +adalService);
         adalService.acquireToken("https://thirumalaivstgit.onmicrosoft.com",function(errorDesc,token,error){
            console.log("afterlogin error");
            console.log(errorDesc);
            console.log(token);
            console.log(error);
        }); 
        console.log("afterlogin000000");
    }

    $scope.getvalue=function()
    {
    console.log("asdfasdfsdfg");      
console.log("getvalue::"+adalService.userInfo.profile);
            for (var property in adalService.userInfo.profile) {
                if (adalService.userInfo.profile.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    $scope.claims.push({
                        key: property,
                        value: adalService.userInfo.profile[property],
                    });
                }
            }
            console.log("getvalue");
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for your application to interpret the access token obtained. The token obtained is designed to be opaque to the client. Adal-angular [implementation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/adal-angular.js#L257) works such that the token obtained is added as a bearer token to the requests made to your app's own backend. The validation of the token happens in the backend or by the web api.

You can take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi) for how to use adal-angular.